# Show two Google maps in one page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The Google code works for one map but I manage to show two maps in one page. The problem is that the `infowindow` and `marker` isn't working for the second map. How do I set this correctly?

HTML

```
<div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
<div id="gmap_canvas2" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
```

JS

```
function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        styles: [{
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -50
            }]
        }],
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.529627, 77.218068),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 12,
        styles: [{
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -50
            }]
        }],
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.529627, 72.218068),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas2'), myOptions2);

    //I don't know how to call this function below separately?

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.529627, 77.218068)
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Welcome'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

How do I differentiate the function into two maps so it loads the values of `infowindow` and `marker` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the following way.

```
function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        styles: [{
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -50
            }]
        }],
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.529627, 77.218068),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var myOptions2 = {
        zoom: 12,
        styles: [{
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -50
            }]
        }],
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.529627, 72.218068),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas2'), myOptions2);

    //FIRST MARKER

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.529627, 77.218068)
    });
    infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Welcome'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
    });
    infowindow1.open(map, marker1);


    //SECOND MARKER

    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map2,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.529627, 72.218068)
    });
    infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Welcome'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        infowindow2.open(map2, marker2);
    });
    infowindow2.open(map2, marker2);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this Answer as correct within 4 minutes when I'm allowed to :)

Comment: @ElaineByene Glad to help you and hope you will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 different `google.maps.Map` objects 2 different `infoWindow` and 2 separate `google.maps.Marker` objects and add each marker to its associated map. See existing example https://codepen.io/Marnoto/pen/VLjVZZ/